# nodetool removenode allows dead node to rejoin when it comes back online

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I remove a dead node from my Cassandra cluster using `nodetool removenode`. 
Running `nodetool status` after indicates that the deleted node no longer exists. However when the dead node comes online, `nodetool status` indicates that the removed node is UP.

Is there any command that prevents dead node from joining the cluster when it is back online?

Comment: Do you no longer want to use the node?  Do you want to repurpose it for another cluster?    It will join the cluster as a new node if it is configured the same way as before.  You could change the node's config to use a different set of seeds and it will not join the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

Once you remove the node you should change cluster name in `cassandra.yaml.` This will prevent this node from rejoining.

The other methods, like changing seeds may or may not work, depending on how the node was expelled from the cluster. It may still have the cluster info in the cache and therefore will use that instead of the list of seed nodes.

But changing the cluster name will 100% prevent it from rejoining.